# flutter beta channel ListView.builder error

Tags: flutter, beta

flutter beta channel ListView.builder error

[image: ListView.builder]

[image: FlatButton]

Comment: please see the image

Comment: What is the error? Did you restart your IDE, vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flutter clean` and restarting the IDE by invalidating the cache must be helpful.